# Find an element of order $45$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{30}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, or explain why it is impossible

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm asked to find the object asked for, or explain why it is impossible. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does the title mean $\mathbb{Z}_{30} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{12}$?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find how to make that symbol

Comment: I've edited your post; see the [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to produce these expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible because the order of an element is the least common multiple of the orders of its coordinates, and $45=3^2\cdot 5$, so one of the coordinates would need to have order divisible by 9.

Comment: Just a minute apart. :) +1

Comment: @AWertheim +1 from me too. I'd have stopped composing when you posted but my phone doesn't let me know if there's a new post while I'm typing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $G = \mathbb{Z}_{30}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{12} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{30}\times\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. Since $G$ is the direct product of two abelian groups, the order of any element $(a, b) \in G$ is $\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$. Now use Lagrange.